# Date is not coming out correctly in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having a strange issue 
i have sent the date like below
2020-05-26T13:53:01.762+0000
i see in kibana like below
020-05-26T13: 53:01.762+0000

This is causing not to populate fields correctly.

Can you Please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format in index pattern settings for that field.
[In the index pattern settings page for a date field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bOhB.png)